# streamed video stop playing in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, video, actionscript

I have developed video recorder and player. Which will recorder video to flash media server.

When i start recording i set camera quality as following

```
cam.setQuality(65536, 65);
mic.setRate(44);
```

I will record perfectly on save video. Video will move from streaming folder to another folder. On play click video will play that place.

Now, problem is when i start playing then video played some second and then stop playing. Only volume i can listen. Video will not playing.

What is the issue of that? 
Is some frames cut or bandwidth issue?

**Edit:**

Initialize camera as follow:

```
cam = Camera.get();
mic = Microphone.get();
mic.setCodec("Speex");
mic.setRate(44);
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
cam.setMode(627,353,24,true);
cam.setLoopback(true);
cam.setQuality(65536, 65);
mic.setRate(44);
```

for record flv:

```
ns.publish(fileName, "record");
```

**Ex.** Currently i record video of 5 minute then i play it so, it played upto only 2:10 then after it stops playing video and play only audio. same happen when play with vlc player.

If i record with same code locally stream server then works perfectly.

Comment: I think that's may be a metadata problem, could you verify that ? And, did you got a `NetStatusEvent` fired when your video stream is stopped ? And what about trying your video with another video player like vlc, ... ?

Comment: @akmozo In vlc also same video stop at same place only audio playing.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the saving-function. Could you post it? Maybe there is a problem of to big bandwitdth. Try to set the quality lower.

Comment: @AndreLehnert i edited my question check. I tried that first it `setQuality(65536, 90)` i changed it with  `setQuality(65536, 65)`

Comment: I mean the bandwidth. Try `setQuality(8192, 0)`. And look if something is changing with your output file.

Comment: @AndreLehnert sorry for late reply. I set `setQuality(8192, 0)` but still same issue in windows pc. from mac working fine.